# Deleting Row in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row, corresponding-records

This might be a dumb question, but I'm new to SQLite and I can't seem to figure this out.  I have 1 table that has columns `KEY_ROWID`, `KEY_NAME`, `KAY_LATITUDE`, and `KEY_LONGITUDE`.  I want the user to be able to select one and delete it; Can anyone give me a direction to start in?  My question is in the actual deletion of the row given only its name.

Relevant code:

```
public class BeaconDatabase {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "beacon_name";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "beacon_lat";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "beacon_lon";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="BeaconDatabase";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="beaconTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper helper;
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public BeaconDatabase(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public BeaconDatabase open() {
        helper = new DbHelper(this.context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        helper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, Double lat, Double lon) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_LATITUDE, lat);
        cv.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, lon);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public void deleteEntry(long row) {

              // Deletes a row given its rowId, but I want to be able to pass
              // in the name of the KEY_NAME and have it delete that row.
              //db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + row, null);
    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iLat = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LATITUDE);
        int iLon = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LONGITUDE);

        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
            result += cursor.getString(iRow) + ": " + cursor.getString(iName) + " - " + cursor.getDouble(iLat) + " latitude " + cursor.getDouble(iLon) + " longitude\n";
        }

        return result;

    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_LATITUDE + " DOUBLE, " +
                    KEY_LONGITUDE + " DOUBLE);"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: go with @iDroid answer... as it is going to work for me. Thanks iDroid.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
 //---deletes a particular title---
public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null) > 0;
}
```

or

```
public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{name}) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Vijay's answer is the correct because this solution allows to do an SQL injection which is a security leak. For instance: use the value of the name argument: `name = "TRUE; <any SQL command>;"` => 'any SQL command' will be executed. Of course it is not a problem if there is no GUI for that feature.

Comment: @bdevay My answer is about the background task we done with query. So it is not related to the UI. You just have to give information as dynamically so there is no need of security. If you follow the vijay's answer and some one do reverse engineering then you might got information about table with in the database and field you are compering. which i am doing directly in the query so there is no chance to have it leek.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer: of course if there is no user input or other kind of external query maniplation possibility then the security risk is not higher than with the other solution. Continue in the next comment...

Comment: ... But I don't agree with the reverse engineering part of your comment. You have to define somewhere and somehow your query which means that reverse engineering is always a possible security leak (even in case of your solution), especially in Java even if the source is obfuscated. It can only raise the hacking time more. On other hand Google's recommendation is using selection arguments, please check this article: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DeleteDbRow)

Comment: I mean with the concept of not giving static value to the any method or any variable. That should be maximum of dynamical. So that it is more secure then giving static value. Anyway its up to user that how much secure he/she wants to make their app.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer i did come across this and i am loving the answer but i gotta ask how you handle this querty from the activity.Ihave beeen stuck on this from a really long while now.Please help

Comment: @SteveKamau I hope you have made databaseHelper class where you are doing all the database related operations. Here you can put this method and use it from any activity by making object of this DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer please check out my question here-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161944/how-to-delete-a-single-row-in-android-sqlite?noredirect=1#comment50334196_31161944

Comment: @SteveKamau I have answer you on your question. Have a look at that and let me know

Comment: You can try like this:

     //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "= '"+ name +"'", null) > 0;
    }


Otherwise you get error where it says there is no such column

Answer (score 164):

Try like that may you get your solution

```
String table = "beaconTable";
String whereClause = "_id=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(row) };
db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 64):

it's better to use whereargs too;

```
db.delete("tablename","id=? and name=?",new String[]{"1","jack"});
```

this is like useing this command:

```
delete from tablename where id='1' and name ='jack'
```

and using delete function in such way is good because it removes sql injections.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I think it is worth  to use the `whereargs`.

Comment: @Enkahi Is this is like prepared statements in SQLite? I have used this `id=?` kinda syntax with PHP before and it seems very similar to that.

Answer (score 17):

Till i understand your question,you want to put two conditions to select a row to be deleted.for that,you need to do:

```
public void deleteEntry(long row,String key_name) {

      db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + row + " and " + KEY_NAME + "=" + key_name, null);

      /*if you just have key_name to select a row,you can ignore passing rowid(here-row) and use:

      db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + key_name, null);
      */  

}
```

Answer (score 15):

## Try this code

```
public void deleteRow(String value)
{
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();       
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COlUMN_NAME+"='"+value+"'");
db.close();
}
```

Comment: How do i call this when i want to delete? db.deleteRow();

Comment: we can call it by passing value as parameter which you want to delete . Call as db.deleteRow("name");

Answer (score 8):

Try this code...

```
private static final String mname = "'USERNAME'";
public void deleteContact()
{
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_NAME + "=" + mname, null);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works perfectly:

```
public boolean deleteSingleRow(String rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

You can also refer to [this example](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/02/mysql/android-sqlite-insert-update-delete-and-display-data/).

Comment: associated link is dead now .correct one is http://web.archive.org/web/20110309080938/http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/02/mysql/android-sqlite-insert-update-delete-and-display-data/

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **SQLiteDatabase**   then there is a delete method

**Definition of Delete**

```
int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

**Example Implementation**

Now we can write a method called **delete with argument** as name

```
public void delete(String value) {
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(value)});
}
```

if you want to **delete all records** then just pass null to the above method,

```
public void delete() {
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}
```

[Source Of Information](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Comment: If String value   is attached with foreign key  then ??

Answer (score 2):

Guys this is a generic method you can use for all your tables, Worked perfectly in my case.

```
public void deleteRowFromTable(String tableName, String columnName, String keyValue) {
    String whereClause = columnName + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(keyValue)};
    yourDatabase.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: String.ValueOf(keyValue) => can you please explain this line?

Comment: No need of String.ValueOf(keyValue), because the keyValue is already string. in other cases we are using this whereArgs Array to identify the column name value.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code-

```
mSQLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();//To delete , database should be writable.
int rowDeleted = mSQLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME,id + " =?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
mSQLiteDatabase.close();//This is very important once database operation is done.
if(rowDeleted != 0){
    //delete success.
} else {
    //delete failed.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete rows from a table, you need to provide selection criteria that identify the rows to the `delete()` method. The mechanism works the same as the selection arguments to the `query()` method. It divides the selection specification into a selection clause(where clause) and selection arguments.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
     // Define 'where' part of query.
    String selection = Contract.COLUMN_COMPANY_ID + " =?  and "
                       + Contract.CLOUMN_TYPE +" =? ";
   // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
    String[] selectionArgs = { cid,mode };
    // Issue SQL statement.
    int deletedRows = db.delete(Contract.TABLE_NAME, 
                       selection, selectionArgs);
    return deletedRows;// no.of rows deleted.
```

The return value for the `delete()` method indicates the number of rows that were deleted from the database.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Guys if above solutions don't work for you then try this one also because it worked for me.

```
public boolean deleteRow(String name) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "='" + name +"' ;", null) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Works great!**

```
public void deleteNewMelk(String melkCode) {
    getWritableDatabase().delete(your_table, your_column +"=?", new String[]{melkCode});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public void deleteEntry(long rowId) {
    database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE , KEY_ROWID 
        + " = " + rowId, null);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean deleteRow(long l) {
    String where = "ID" + "=" + l;
    return db.delete(TABLE_COUNTRY, where, null) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, sharing my working code snippet

Make sure query is like this

> DELETE FROM   tableName WHERE 
>                       KEY__NAME = 'parameterToMatch'

```
public void removeSingleFeedback(InputFeedback itemToDelete) {
            //Open the database
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

            //Execute sql query to remove from database
            //NOTE: When removing by String in SQL, value must be enclosed with ''
            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_FEEDBACKS + " WHERE "
                    + KEY_CUSTMER_NAME + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrCustName() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_DESIGNATION + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrCustDesignation() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_EMAIL + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrCustEmail() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_CONTACT_NO + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrCustContactNo() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_MOBILE_NO + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrCustMobile() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_CLUSTER_NAME + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrClusterName() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_PRODUCT_NAME + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrProductName() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_INSTALL_VERSION + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrInstalledVersion() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_REQUIREMENTS + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrRequirements() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_CHALLENGES + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrChallenges() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_EXPANSION + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrFutureExpansion() + "'" +
                    " AND " + KEY_COMMENTS + "= '" + itemToDelete.getStrComments() + "'"
            );

            //Close the database
            database.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me was this

```
fun removeCart(mCart: Cart) {
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    val deleteLineWithThisValue = mCart.f
    db.delete(cons.tableNames[3], Cart.KEY_f + "  LIKE  '%" + deleteLineWithThisValue + "%' ", null)
}


class Cart {
    var a: String? = null
    var b: String? = null
    var c: String? = null
    var d: String? = null
    var e: Int? = null
    var f: String? = null

companion object {
    // Labels Table Columns names
    const val rowIdKey = "_id"
    const val idKey = "id"
    const val KEY_a = "a"
    const val KEY_b = "b"
    const val KEY_c = "c"
    const val KEY_d = "d"
    const val KEY_e = "e"
    const val KEY_f = "f"
   }
}

object cons {
    val tableNames = arrayOf(
            /*0*/ "shoes",
            /*1*/ "hats",
            /*2*/ "shirt",
            /*3*/ "car"
         )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

But the Accepted answer Not worked for me. I think String should be In SQL, strings must be quoted. So, in my case this worked for me against the accepted answer :

```
 database.delete(TABLE_DAILY_NOTES, WORK_ENTRY_CLUMN_NAME + "='" + workEntry+"'", null);
```