# Deleting from SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB with a table called "students". In the students table, there are 2 columns: "student_id" and "student_name".

I am trying to delete a row from an SQLite table using this code:

```
String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students";
String COLUMN_STUDENTNAME= "student_name";

public void deleteUser(String name) {
    database.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS, COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + "=" + name, null);
}
```

However, when I try to delete the user "John" I get this error message from LogCat

```
12-19 16:28:47.132: E/SQLiteLog(14883): (1) no such column: John
```

I was trying to follow the example here: [Deleting Row in SQLite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android), but I could swear my syntax is the same.

Guessing I am doing something stupid, but anyone able to help? Thanks.

Comment: The answer below works great. The other way that works which is what I was going for was `database.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS, COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + "=\"" + name + "\"", null);` I forgot to put quotes around it. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: That's something you should not do: http://bobby-tables.com/ (There are people out there that have an `'` in their name and that will break your code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try:

```
database.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS,COLUMN_STUDENTNAME +" = ?", new String[] { name });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is sending the equivalent statement `DELETE FROM students WHERE student_name=John`, which is why it is looking for a column called John.  You need to use the third parameter of the method to provide the argument, so:

```
final String[] deleteConditions = new String[]{ name };
database.delete(TABLE_STUDENTS, COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + "=?", deleteConditions);
```

Note that you can delete multiple rows by adding more entries to the array `deleteConditions`.

Comment: "Note that you can delete multiple rows by adding more entries to the array deleteConditions" - please explain, in this form it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

That works, although I would recommend

```
db.delete(TABLE, "column_name=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(custname) });
```

or use

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "  + COLUM_NAME+ " = " + "'"+VALUE +"'" ;
db.execSQL(query);
```