# How to delete items from a database

Tags: java, android, database, listview

I am making an app that stores a name and a mark in a database and it displays this in a listview. How can I delete an item of the listview and also of the database with a long press of the item in the listview??

Here is the code of the database helper:

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    public static String query;

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations
    public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }

    public void average() {
        String query = "SELECT AVG("+PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN +") FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        database.rawQuery(query, null);




    }
}
```

Comment: what you have tried and didn't worked?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Detecting the long press? deleting the entry from the databse? Something else?

Comment: For deleting an entry from db , refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510442/2319542) In order to reflect changes to the listview don't forget to call `listview.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: In StackOverflow, it is usually best to ask only one question at a time. So for your question, I would divide it into 2 questions: 1 for the db, 1 for the long press. Afa the SQLite db part, I recommend using a class like this. It is a `SQLiteManager` class which wraps around an inner class `SQLiteHelper`: https://gist.github.com/scruffyfox/7943376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you have a unique ID associated with each entry in your database, you could delete based on that, like so:

```
public void deleteItem(int itemId){
    this.getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + "=" + itemId, null);
}
```

Then, when an item in your `ListView` is long-pressed, you could call that method to remove it from your database, and then call `remove(Object)` on your `Adapter` (or `remove(int)` on the `List` your `Adapter` uses), followed by `notifyDataSetChanged()` to ensure it updates the display correctly.

*Edit*: To answer your question about how to apply a long click listener to an item in your `ListView`, it depends on how you've implemented the `Adapter`. If it's's a custom adapter, you can simply set an `onLongClickListener()` to your root `View` (e.g. convertView). If you're not using that, you can try attaching an `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` like this to your `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        // get the data from your list at position, i.e. data.get(position)
        // then pass that object / id to your database helper, e.g.

        Person p = data.get(position);
        personDatabaseHelper.deleteItem(p.getId());

        data.remove(position); // or adapter.remove(p), depends on your implementation
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // remove the object from your Adapter and notify it of the change

        return true;
    }
});
```

`Edit 2:` Using a custom Adapter

In your getView() method, add the following before returning convertView:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // your other stuff here

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Person p = getItem(position);

            personDatabaseHelper.deleteItem(p.getId());  
            remove(p);

            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            return true;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, the problem is that I can not use getWritableDatabase() because it says: "can't resolve method getWritableDatabase"

Comment: Try changing "this.getWritableDatabase()) to "database" since you already have an instance of database in your PersonDatabaseHelper class defined  when instantiated.

Comment: thanks, it has worked. How can I can call the public void deleteItem from my mainactiviy with a long press of one item of the listview? can you show me the code?

Comment: I tried to answer that in the main post, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but how can make it if I have a custom adapter?

Comment: Pretty much the same, except using View.setOnLongClickListener. See my edit

Comment: thank you for the answer but I can't do tat becouse it says "can't resolve symbols" in all the lines of the code that are inside the boolean onLongClick

Comment: can I send you an email with my cursor adapter to look at it please? this will help me a lot

Comment: See my edit. You need to replace the values with what your adapter is using / has access to. Assuming you have a custom ArrayAdapter, you could get the Person object that you're referring to by calling getItem(position) from inside the adapter. You need to change personDatabaseHelper to point to your instance of the PersonDatabaseHelper you used to get the people from in the first place. You also would then replace "data.remove(position)" with "remove(person)". And lastly, "position" has to be declared as final in the getView() params else you won't be able to access it.