# Deleting the last item in a list in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android simple To Do list app for learning purposes.

This is my function which updates the UI with the list items:

```
private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK },//, TaskContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK}, //TaskContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION },
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

I need an SQlite statement to delete the last item from the list. As I am new to Android, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a row in Android is already covered in the SO question 
[Deleting Row in SQLite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android). Essentially, you use the `delete()` method on your `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
db.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

So, as an example:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(keyIdOfRowToDelete) } );
```

The correct `KEY_ID` of the row you want to delete is on the last row of your cursor, accessible with the `moveToLast()` method:

```
cursor.moveToLast();
int keyIdOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_COLUMN_NAME));
```

After you have deleted the necessary entry, run another `query()`, as you have done in your question, to refresh the `Cursor`, and update your `SimpleCursorAdapter` by first calling `swapCursor()` with the new cursor, then `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
listAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to count the items of the list, using something like `count` or `length`, then get the item by index (get the index with counted items) and delete it