# How to delete row from DataBase in android

Tags: android, android-database

I want delete row from `SQLiteDataBase` but i can't it and i that ID is not correctly filled! When select Delete button show me `"Data Not Deleted"` Toast message.

**Attention :** Please do not disappoint me and don't give me negative points. I searched online but could not find a suitable method for this I raised in my question here.Please guide me because I am amateur.

**My DataProvider code :**

```
public class DataProvider implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public DataProvider(String id, String  name, String family, String password, String phone, String email) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**My SQLiteOpenHelder code and delete query :**

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfoDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT);";

    public UserDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "Database Create / Open...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "Table Create...");
    }


    public void AddUserInfo(String name, String family, String password, String phone, String email, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY, family);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);

        db.insert(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "One row inserted...");
    }

    public Cursor getUserInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        String list_sort = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ID + " DESC";

        cursor = db.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, list_sort);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor searchContacts(String user_name, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        String selection = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {user_name};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public Integer deleteUserInfo(String id, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        return db.delete(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id});
    }

    public Boolean login(String username, String password, SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + "=? AND " +
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{username, password});

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

**Main Activity code to send data :**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        DataProvider dataprovider = (DataProvider) listDataAdapter.getItem(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("share_data", dataprovider);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, UserPage.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**Delete button code in second Activity :**

```
delete_btn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.user_delete_button);
delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        DataProvider dataprovider = (DataProvider) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("share_data");
        sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String USER_id = dataprovider.getId();
        Integer deleteRaw = userDbHelper.deleteUserInfo(USER_id, sqLiteDatabase);

        if (deleteRaw > 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

**LogCat code:**

```
02-18 13:03:20.732 6124-6124/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-18 13:03:20.860 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject themeResourceId=2131296386
02-18 13:03:20.899 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
02-18 13:03:20.917 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
02-18 13:03:20.917 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
02-18 13:03:20.963 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/DATABASE OPERATION :: Database Create / Open...
02-18 13:03:20.964 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
02-18 13:03:20.972 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
02-18 13:03:20.972 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
02-18 13:03:21.080 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/CliptrayUtils: CliptrayUtils created!! mTextView = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{3d035869 VFED..C. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0c007a app:id/login_user_text}
02-18 13:03:21.086 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/CliptrayUtils: CliptrayUtils created!! mTextView = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{383e51c6 VFED..C. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0c007d app:id/login_pass_text}
02-18 13:03:21.133 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
02-18 13:03:21.134 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                                 Build Date: 01/21/15 Wed
                                                                                 Local Branch: mybranch7061829
                                                                                 Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.7
                                                                                 Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                 Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013 +  NOTHING
02-18 13:03:21.139 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-18 13:03:21.167 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-18 13:03:21.205 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-18 13:03:21.562 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.562 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.563 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.563 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.613 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/CliptrayUtils: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
02-18 13:03:21.744 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/CliptrayUtils: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
02-18 13:03:21.782 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.782 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.782 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.782 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:21.783 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e76a338 time:19996341
02-18 13:03:22.184 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:22.185 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:22.185 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:22.185 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:26.818 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-18 13:03:26.846 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-18 13:03:27.042 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.042 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.042 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.042 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.097 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.097 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.097 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.097 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.868 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/art: Thread[1,tid=6124,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x75cbeda8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
02-18 13:03:27.880 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/MediaProfilesEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaProfilesEx
02-18 13:03:27.880 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/MediaRecorderEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaRecorderEx
02-18 13:03:27.881 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/AudioSystemEx: register_com_lge_media_LGAudioSystem
02-18 13:03:27.881 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/SurfaceControlEx: register_com_lge_view_SurfaceControlEx
02-18 13:03:27.881 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/art: Thread[1,tid=6124,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x75cbeda8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
02-18 13:03:27.881 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/LGMtpDatabaseJNI: register_android_mtp_LGMtpDatabase
02-18 13:03:27.882 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/art: Thread[1,tid=6124,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x75cbeda8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
02-18 13:03:27.883 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/LGMtpServerJNI: register_android_mtp_LGMtpServer
02-18 13:03:27.886 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/art: Thread[1,tid=6124,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x75cbeda8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
02-18 13:03:27.886 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/MediaPlayerEx-jni: register_com_lge_view_MediaPlayerEx
02-18 13:03:27.887 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/art: Thread[1,tid=6124,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x75cbeda8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
02-18 13:03:27.921 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:27.921 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:29.390 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-18 13:03:29.451 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-18 13:03:29.454 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/CliptrayUtils: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
02-18 13:03:30.545 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:30.545 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
02-18 13:03:31.558 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-18 13:03:31.651 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-18 13:03:31.667 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject time:20006225
02-18 13:03:31.680 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
02-18 13:03:31.681 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject themeResourceId=2131296386
02-18 13:03:31.682 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
02-18 13:03:31.684 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
02-18 13:03:31.684 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
02-18 13:03:31.704 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/DATABASE OPERATION :: Database Create / Open...
02-18 13:03:32.119 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3443294b time:20006677
02-18 13:03:34.733 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-18 13:03:34.793 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-18 13:03:34.869 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject time:20009427
02-18 13:03:34.968 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject themeResourceId=2131296386
02-18 13:03:34.996 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
02-18 13:03:35.002 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
02-18 13:03:35.002 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
02-18 13:03:35.241 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/DATABASE OPERATION :: Database Create / Open...
02-18 13:03:35.836 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
02-18 13:03:35.845 6124-6154/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject V/RenderScript: 0xaf412c00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
02-18 13:03:35.920 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@16dd805c time:20010477
02-18 13:03:38.727 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
02-18 13:03:38.804 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
02-18 13:03:38.805 6124-6124/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject E/DATABASE OPERATION :: Database Create / Open...
02-18 13:04:17.593 6124-6134/com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.071ms
```

Please help me, because i need to this tutorial. tnx for all dears <3

Comment: Describe your problem properly first.

Comment: @MD, i say it : When select Delete button show me "Data Not Deleted" Toast message. i can't delete row, and when select delete button not deleted row!

Comment: Post your logcat output. That would contain the reason.

Comment: You can delete row by `position`

Comment: @Yashasvi, LogCat output inserted

Comment: This is not the full output of logcat. Check again and post.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, How do it? please help me bu code. thanks

Comment: @Yashasvi, update this. please reload page

Comment: Are you sure the USER_id that you are passing is valid?

Comment: put a log statement in delete function to check all the values.

Comment: @Yashasvi, I also have my doubts on this case and I do not know where is the problem

Comment: yes you have to log in function..!!

Comment: @NilsPatel, how to fix it?

Comment: try this link it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: What I need top understand is why did you set `id` as a string in your `DataProvider` Class: `private String id;`. When `id` is an **INTEGER** in the DataBase Table. I would fix that, first.

Comment: This because some implicit type casting from integer to string may occur during the query string build process.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, please send me full code, i really need this code. 3 days' i'm looking for this problem. please help me my dear friend

Comment: I can't rewrite your whole code. But even follow the answer below (which I fixed) OR change the `id` type to **int** in your `DataProvider` Class. It should be enough. Recommended: search some tutorial on CRUD operations in Android with SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not selecting `id` from your database. so when you try to get `id` from your `Cursor` it will return `null`, then you pass that value to your delete function and try to delete a record whose id is null, and there is not any record that its id is null. so nothing will be deleted.

add `id` to your projection list when you select data from your database , and you will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter @name  to delete the row you want.

```
public boolean deleteTitle(String name) {        

     return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'", null) > 0; 

}
```

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, can you help me?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi yes it would  require the literals ! sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Fixed your code by adding the string (`'`) literal markers.