# How to bind cardview to SQLite row in datebase Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView with CardView. I can create Card and I can insert data from that card to my database. Now I can delete this CardView. How can I delete that CardView from my database?

Thanks! And sorry for my bad English :)

Fragment of CardViewAdapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    CardViewDebt card = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.mWho.setText(card.getWho());
    holder.mWhom.setText(card.getWhom());
    holder.mWhat.setText(card.getTarget());
    holder.mStart.setText(card.getStartYear() + "/" + (card.getStartMonth() + 1) + "/" + card.getStartDay());
    holder.mEnd.setText(card.getEndYear() + "/" + (card.getEndMonth() + 1) + "/" + card.getEndDay());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                DBHelper DataBase = new DBHelper(holder.mContext);
                SQLiteDatabase db = DataBase.getWritableDatabase();
                Log.d("Delete row in Database", "--- Delete from mytable: ---");
                db.delete("debt", "id = " + position, null);  <----Thats wrong
                mDataset.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So your question is how to delete record from Sqlite database? Doesn't that answer helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android ?

Comment: @Divers, No, it isn't. Check my code, please. I want to delete record with information about cardview which i have chosen.
`db.delete("debt", "id = " + position, null);`. It's wrong because id!=position in ArrayList.

Comment: Use id of your card, not position in list.

Comment: @Divers, I know. But how can I know this id, this card id?

Comment: `card.getId()` or something?

Comment: @Divers. Thanks! I forgot about this :D Sorry and thanks :)