# How to delete a specific row in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table `address (id,name,phone,address)`.
I expose the details `(name,phone,address)` in a list view.

I am adding a `onCLick` function for each row in the list to delete it. How to delete only that row when we do not have the primary_key with us. i.e we have only `(name,phone,address)` with us. There may be duplicate rows, so do not want to delete multiple rows.

If I give `delete from address where name ='name_val' and phone = 'phone_val' and address='address_val'`, it will delete all the rows that match the condition which I do not intend to do.

The DB code.

```
public List<String> getAllRecords(){

    String query = "Select  * FROM "+ TABLE_ACT;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    List activities = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String actData= c.getString(1)+"\n"+c.getString(2)+"\n"+c.getString(3);
            //getString(1) is name, getString(2) is phone, getString(3) is address
            activities.add(actData);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return activities;
}
```

Above method returns a list of Strings.This is used in the activity as shown below.

```
lists = dbHandler.getAllRecords();
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lists);
```

and it has onItemClickListener that is inherited from ListActivity.

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.e("Hello", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);


    }
```

Kindly help me delete a particular row given that only Name,phone and address is present in ListItem.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: Use the id from the selected row.

Comment: can u put ur code here

Comment: see `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` documentation - `onItemClick` method in particular, it has the `long id` parameter, use it when deleting your row from the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Row in SQLite in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android)

Comment: Kindly review my answer

Comment: You should use a CursorAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void deleteItem(String get_ID)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Table_Name WHERE TABLE_ID='"+get_ID+"'");
}
```

**OnClick** Method

```
viewOBJ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          myDbOBJ = new Your_Data_Base_Class(getContext());
                  myDbOBJ.deleteItem("1"); // set Dynamic
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      });
```

**NOTE**

**`get_ID`**  will be **String** or **Integer**. For best approach **TABLE_ID** should be **Primary Key** .

Comment: Which class contains this method?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Please check my updated question with code snippets.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, Please check my updated question with code snippets.

Comment: @CS_noob You should ping each person only once.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, was little anxious. I will do as told, going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the id from the selected row:

```
delete from address
where id = id_val
```

If you are using a CursorAdapter as you should, then you can call `getItemId()`:

```
long id = getItemId(position);
String where = "id=?";
String whereArgs = { Long.toString(id) };
db.delete(tableName, where, whereArgs);
```

This can go directly in your OnClickListener or in your database helper. Note that I assume you already have an open SQLiteDatabase object. If not, you will have to open one.