# can anyone tell me what's wrong in this?

Tags: sqlite

```
public  void deleteData(String name,int itemID){

    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    String query="DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ "'"+ COL1 +"'"+ " = "+ itemID + " AND "+ "'" + COL2 + "'" +" ="+ " '"+ name + "'";
   db.execSQL(query);

    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Row in SQLite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510219/deleting-row-in-sqlite-in-android)

Comment: Single quotes in SQL are used to enclose string literals. It seems like you enclose the names of your columns in single quotes making them string literals and therefore nothing matches.

Comment: You should bind values to parameters in your query instead of trying to include them directly in a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following are wrong or could be considered as wrong.

1. There should be no need to call the exact same query twice.
2. It is considered better to use the Android SDK's convenience methods when they suit (instead of using the **execSQL** method the **delete** method is more appropriate).
3. There is the potential for SQLinjection attacks when parameters are used directly in strings that are executed directly as SQL (note resolving 2 and using the appropriate parameters resolves this issue).
4. There is, unless the columns are named with invalid names, no need to enclose column names in single quotes or alternative characters (invalid names can make life difficult so if used they would be considered wrong by many).
5. If the delete (the first one), is not working or if the delete appears to not return an appropriate result after using `pragma count_changes` that could be due to the row not existing (did the row get inserted?) or that the 2nd query which would delete nothing is hiding the result of the first query.

   1. `pragma count_changes` is deprecated in later version of SQLite so should no longer be used (albeit that Android's SQlite version is typically some way behind).

As a fix to all bar the id not existing you could use the following :-

```
public  int deleteData(String name,int itemID){

    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = COL1 + "=? AND " + COL2 + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(int),name};
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,whereclause,whereargs);
}
```

- Note that the methods signature results in an **int** being returned, this will be the number of rows deleted.